# Where do the variables in scss files come from and how can I set them

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, sass

I am a newbie to Rails and I noticed in the index.css.scss file that there is a variable for the transition

```
 @include transition(background-color $TRANSITION_DURATION $TRANSITION_EASE_LINEAR);
```

Where are $TRANSITION_DURATION $TRANSITION_EASE_LINEAR set?

I did a grep -R "TRANSITION_DURATION" . and it only found them in index.css.scss, as "sass" directory and some sprockets directories, but I do not see where the variables are being set.

BTW, this is from a github project

The reason why I am asking, is I am trying to apply a different background-color as I learn about Rails

Comment: Are you using Twitter Bootstrap, Foundation or any other CSS framework? Have a look in the project's Gemfile, it's probably there.

Comment: I opened a text editor to look through the Gemfile, but I couldn't find it. Then I ran a search through the folder, via the text editor and it found it in the index.css.scss file. Why didn't my grep find it? Am I doing something wrong in the grep command?

Comment: I mean your Gemfile may have some info about CSS Framework used in the project. Those variables may well be defined there, in the gems files (not the project's ones).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[SCSS Variables](http://sass-lang.com/guide) are set in scope (same way functions handle local & global vars):

```
#app/assets/stylesheets/application.css.scss
@red = #ff0; -> accessible through all dependent files

.title { 
    @background = #ff0; -> accessible with .title only
}
```

The answer to your question is it will be defined in your CSS somewhere. Best thing is to look at `application.css.scss` & then look at which dependencies are called

It will be defined somewhere in the CSS